# Enyo JS : Set moon.DataGridList collection dynamically

Tags: javascript, enyo

```
Is there away to set a grid collection dynamically after an ajax call ?
```

---

```
.....
        create: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments); 
            this.onFetchItemList();
        },  
        onFetchItemList: function(){
            var prof = this.userProfile;
             obj.getBrowse(prof,function onBrowseCallback(list){
                 this.set("collection", new enyo.Collection(list));
            });
        }
.....
```

---

```
I get this method is undefined when I try to use the set function  
this.$.gridList.set("collection" ,new enyo.Collection(list));
```

---

```
same error here as well :
this.$.gridList.collection.set('collection',this.shows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, simply mistake on my part , whoops :)

```
 onFetchItemList: function(inSender, inEvent){
            var prof = this.userProfile;      
            var _gridList = this.$.gridList;
            var shows = new enyo.Collection();
             obj.getBrowse(prof,function onBrowseCallback(list){
                ameba_lastListViewed = [];
                ameba_lastListViewed = list;
                shows = new enyo.Collection(list); 
                  _gridList.set('collection',shows);
        }
```